# Is it possible to remove or disable the esm apps in software update GUI format, since I don't have Ubuntu Pro, more info in the post

Tags: apt, updates, 22.04, software-center, ubuntu-pro

I have something curious that I would like to get answer, say everything works fine, but I don’t have Ubuntu Pro, however, when in software and updater (I’m using 22.04.03 Lts), I hit update, I get this:

As you can see in the image, are the ESM-apps, Ubuntu Pro, that I know I do not have any installed, unless it is ffmpeg (Which I have is named Chromium-ffmpeg and is a SNAP).

The question, is that it jumps me for 4 days, and although the updates come out and are updated, never gives me the message that your system is updated, because it considers pending ESM-apps, which I find curious because I do not have any of them that I know, and if already in the Faq, that if you match any can jump this message, but in all these years, I had never jumped the one that you have esm-apps to update.

If I do the update by terminal, no problem I do not jump, just tells me the message that if I want such esm-apps, I enroll in Ubuntu Pro, so I find it curious, that GUI format, ie Software and updater (Software Update), I jump directly that are to install, and not the message inscribite, if you want them.

Thank you for your time, best regards.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnyC0.png)

Comment: Tl;dr your question please.

Comment: The question is how to remove or prevent the esm-apps from the Gui, since I do not have Ubuntu pro, and I got the image 4 days ago, everything is updated normally.

Comment: Please edit to clearly state your question inside your question.